Help Requested Formulating Mathematical Train Car Problem
At the same time every day, a train stops along a track and you count the number of cars attached to it and the number of objects within it. You note the following observations.
The number of train cars attached is a random amount, as are the number of objects within each train car. What you do know (or at least for simplicity are assuming given the number of times you've investigated one of these stopped trains) is that for the $n$ train cars, you have $20 \leq n \leq 40$ carrying $O = \sum_{i=1}^{k}O_i$ objects where $O_i$ is the number of objects in train car $i$.
For a more concrete example, maybe this time you see the train has $n = 30$ train cars attached to it, and $c_{1}$ (train car 1) has $O_1 = 2$ objects in it; $c_2$ has $O_2 = 15$ objects in it, and $c_{30}$ has $O_{30} = 10$ objects within it.
The question/idea I had was regarding answering the questions "What is the average amount of objects contained within a car?"  and "What is the probability that I sample any car and it has at least this many objects within it" or similarly "What is the probability that I sample any car and it has this amount of objects within it?"
I'm not sure if I've formulated this quite right but this question can be further stratified into one involving historical data existing and one without said historical data. The case of having data makes this a lot simpler as they're just manual calculations.
For example, if I had a dataset of observed count data such as something like this (rows are a given train observation with some variable number of cars and their observed object counts, columns are the specific train cars and the number of items within them for any given train):
$ \begin{matrix}
12 & 4 & 18 & 8 & 7 & 18 & 10 & 11 & 14 & 18 & 5 & 8 & 19 & 13 & 3 & 13 & 2 & 9 & 13 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
10 & 16 & 17 & 7 & 13 & 4 & 13 & 16 & 4 & 19 & 5 & 2 & 7 & 12 & 5 & 2 & 13 & 6 & 17 & 19 & 5 & 1 & 20 & 12 & 12 & 20 & 5 & 20 & 17 & 2 & 16 & 20 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
14 & 17 & 7 & 2 & 8 & 16 & 12 & 12 & 5 & 5 & 19 & 2 & 19 & 19 & 14 & 2 & 19 & 8 & 11 & 7 & 14 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
18 & 12 & 16 & 4 & 19 & 10 & 16 & 13 & 2 & 10 & 18 & 20 & 8 & 16 & 8 & 16 & 12 & 11 & 7 & 11 & 16 & 17 & 11 & 18 & 12 & 18 & 11 & 17 & 18 & 16 & 13 & 8 & 20 & 17 & 15 & 17 & 6 & 20 & 19 & 19 \\
4 & 17 & 15 & 13 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 19 & 9 & 8 & 14 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 17 & 16 & 20 & 18 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 16 & 10 & 9 & 17 & 12 & 13 & 11 & 9 & 3 & 10 & 6 & 18 & 17 & 14 & 18 & 15 & 11 & 19 & 15 \\
6 & 14 & 8 & 7 & 13 & 20 & 3 & 19 & 18 & 17 & 2 & 2 & 18 & 8 & 9 & 12 & 18 & 16 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 14 & 19 & 3 & 8 & 19 & 6 & 6 & 15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 9 & 10 & 9 & 15 & 7 & 2 & 11 & 10 & 6 & 20 & 20 & 7 & 9 & 17 & 3 & 5 & 9 & 17 & 13 & 2 & 7 & 6 & 11 & 16 & 17 & 7 & 13 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
11 & 17 & 5 & 17 & 3 & 10 & 13 & 16 & 3 & 3 & 14 & 20 & 16 & 8 & 8 & 14 & 12 & 8 & 8 & 17 & 18 & 7 & 16 & 5 & 20 & 11 & 1 & 4 & 13 & 12 & 8 & 11 & 20 & 4 & 17 & 16 & 17 & 1 & 14 & 6 \\
14 & 19 & 17 & 15 & 9 & 7 & 8 & 18 & 19 & 10 & 12 & 5 & 7 & 14 & 6 & 18 & 14 & 9 & 17 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 9 & 18 & 3 & 18 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 14 & 7 & 12 & 13 & 15 & 19 & 4 & 15 & 3 & 0 \\
17 & 4 & 13 & 6 & 13 & 2 & 19 & 19 & 12 & 19 & 3 & 6 & 18 & 4 & 12 & 6 & 3 & 10 & 10 & 8 & 19 & 6 & 13 & 6 & 7 & 18 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}  $
I can see that train 1 ($t_{1}$) has $20$ cars and on average, is carrying $5.55$ objects (we'll round up and say $6$) in it, and that $c_{1}$ has on average $11$ objects within it. This can be done mutatis mutandis for the other trains and cars too. Then these probability questions become a lot easier.
If you DON'T have historical data though, it seems this question becomes a lot harder and that's with what I'm struggling. I'm thinking that the number of train cars is a random variable, as are the number of objects contained within each train car. We'll let $X$ be the number of train cars and $Y$ be the number of objects within each train car.
It seems that $X$ and $Y$ would both be Binomial Random Variables but I'm not sure what their specifics are assuming I'm even right here (big assumption). I know a Binomial Distribution is just the sum of $N$ Bernoulli Trials with some probability of success $p$ happening, but I'm not sure how to translate that to this problem I'm describing. It further seems like I'd have to consider joint and/or marginal probability distributions depending on the specific question I'm trying to answer.
Oh, and I guess given the historical data case, what if I saw a new train and wanted to make statistical inference on it? Is that when it'd turn into a Bayesian Stats problem?
I apologize for all the questions, but I was sitting here thinking of my youth because this is what me and my grandpa would often do when we could. A train ran through the back of his property and would always stop for about an hour and so we'd sometimes count the number of train cars and the number of objects within them (most often they were just various motor vehicles).
But yes, without having historical data, is there a way to write a closed-form solution to finding out the probability of observing a train car with at least some $\alpha$ amount of objects within them or some specified $\gamma$ amount of objects within a train car?
Thanks!

Why would you think these are binomial random variables?  You might be able to justify such assumptions if you had a suitable model of how the trains are put together and how objects are chosen to be put in the cars.  But without that, there's no reason to think they are binomial.

Should it not be $$O = \sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{n}}O_i ~~\text{objects} ~?$$
